# AngularJS $http query remove special characters

Tags: angularjs, http, special-characters

My problem is simple, every time I try to pass a string with special characters, through a
$http.get() query, some special characters are removed.

In my case, a simple email: emma@watson.com, become emmawatson.com in the query header.

Is Angular doing some sort of validation before sending AJAX query ?

Here is my Ajax code:

```
$http.get(apiUrl,
            {
                params: {
                    username: "Emma",
                    email: "emma@watson.com",
                    password: "1234"
                }
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                //do a simple return of the email on the server
                console.log(data);//"emmawatson.com"
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For http requests, it's strongly recommended to base64 encode your data before sending it.

Try this code and see if it works:

```
$http.get(apiUrl, {
    params: {
        username: "Emma",
        email: window.btoa("emma@watson.com"),
        password: "1234"
    }
})
.success(function (data) {
    //do a simple return of the email on the server
    console.log(data); //"emmawatson.com"
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve my problem with a decode on the server side :)